# обработка хмл файла

Tags: xml, excel, access

Есть хмл файл, который обрабатывается с помощью вба в экселе, но эксель использует всего 1 ядро компьютера и из-за этого обработка происходит 1-2 часа. Прочитал, что можно делать тоже самое в аксесе. Ускорит ли это обработку? Могу ли я уже готовый код использовать в аксес?

Comment: Может можно обрабатывать хмл еще чем-то? там происходит сверка со старыми ценами и их обновление, если есть изменение.

Comment: Ускорит если переписать на `с`. Но без опыта врядли выйдет быстро.

Comment: А через что переписывать? может можно через язык более высокого уровня? с си еще ни разу не сталкивался. Может знаете какую-нибудь литературу с похожим запросом?

Comment: Можно попробовать на js переписать, он долго обрабатывает xml (через XMLDOMDocument) но возможно побыстрее чем excel и access. Довольно хороший результат может дать c#. Есть другие языки JAVA, питон и т д. возможно они тоже датут хороший результат.

Comment: А в c# можно как-то преобразовать уже написанное в вба?

Comment: Нужно смотреть что знаете, и смотреть 1) Есть ли там библиотека работы с хмл, если да, то есть ли работа... с базой или с excel. Я думаю что всётаки база, excel большие обьемы неочень ест.

Comment: Можно создать vb проэкт в студии, он похож на vba будет.

Comment: Преобразовать нет, только ручками перебирать.

Comment: Я как-то переписывал один из макросов для google spreadsheets. Это ява скрипт же? Можно его выполнить вне гугла? Их сервисы выполняют его, но медленнее чем эксель.

Comment: могу дать код вба и гугла.